# Cannot scroll horizontally with iScroll

Tags: javascript, iscroll

I want to scroll horizontally the inner divs in the following html:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="cell">
        cell 1
    </div> 
    <div class="cell">
        cell 2
    </div> 
    <div class="cell">
        cell 3
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Im using [iscroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) to do this. However, im not able to scroll, though the scrollStart event is triggered as I try to scroll. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjp23269/3/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using iScroll.

In CSS, change the #outer overflow value to "scroll" as below

```
#outer{
    ...
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set scrollX to true, like this:

```
var scroll = new IScroll('#outer', {
    scrollX: true
});
```